# Volume and Probability of a region given by a random variable

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am currently reading [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=355745). It is about nearest neighbors of a query point $X_q\in\mathbb{R}^k$ within a point set $P=\{X_i\mid X_i\in\mathbb{R}^k\}$, where the points have distribution $p(X)$ in the record space. Furthermore we are given a distance function $D(Y,Z)$ between two points $Y,Z\in\mathbb{R}^k$.

Now the authors define $S_m(X_q)$ to be the smallest ball in the coordinate space centered at $X_q$ that exactly contains the $m$ points of $P$ closest to $X_q$. That is,
$$S_m(X_q)=\{X\mid D(X,X_q)\leq D(X_q,X_m)\}$$,
where $X_m$ is the $m$th nearest neighbor to $X_q$. The volume $v_m(X_q)$ of this region is
$$v_m(X_q)=\in_{S_m(X_q)}1\: dX,$$
and the probability content of this region $u_m(X_q)$ is defined as
$$u_m(X_q)=\int_{S_m(X_q)}p(X)\:dX,$$
with $0\leq u_m(X_q)\leq 1$.

My questions are:

1. How can I imagine $S_m(X_q)$? Since $X_m$ is not fixed, but depends on the outcome of the $X_i$, shouldn't $S_m(X_q)$ be different for every possible outcome of $X_i$?
2. By definition $S_m(X_q)$ contains the $m$ closest neighbors to $X_q$ from $P$. How can $u_m(X_q)$ be equal to 0, if the integral has positive values on at least those $m$ points? (Or can it only be the case, if these $m$ point form a null set?)
3. What does the value $u_m(X_q)$ tell? Is it the probability that given the distribution $p(X)$, a point lies in $S_m(X_q)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to better understand the definitions of the OP I have made some changes in the notation used (probably already) in the article.

(1) I would make difference between the original random variables, say, $Y_1,Y_2,...Y_n$ and the nearest neighbors of one of them. So let $Y_q$ be one of the random variables ($1\le q \le n)$ and let $X_1,X_2...,X_m$ be its $m$ nearest neighbors.
Also, I would rather use the following notation
$$S_m(Y_q)=\{x\mid D(x,Y_q)\leq D(Y_q,X_m)\}$$
in order to emphasize that the $x$'s are points (randomly chosen, though) in $R^N$ and $Y_q$ and $X_m$ are random variables.  So $S_m(Y_q)$ is a sphere of a random location (centered at $Y_q$) and of random size determined by $X_m$.

(2-3) The following definition had to be edited as well. 
$$v_m(Y_q)=\iint...\int_{S_m(Y_q)}\: dx_1...dx_k,$$
This is the volume of our randomly changing sphere.

The following 
$$u_m(Y_q)=P(Y \in S_m(Y_q)|Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n)=\iint...\int_{S_m(Y_q)}p(x_1,x_2,...x_k)\:dx_1,...dx_k,$$ is the conditional probability that a random variable $Y$ (identically distributed with the $Y_i$'s) would fall into the sphere determined by the $Y_i$'s.

$$u_m(Y_q)=0$$
is possible for $m=0$ because then our sphere shrinks to $Y_q$. It is also $0$ if all the nearest neighbors fall on $Y_q.$

Comment: Thank you for this fast and thorough explanation. This helps me a lot!